# Why doesn't AND work in SQL where and IN clause does

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I type

```
Select * 
from MyTable 
where LoanNumber = 12345 and LoanNumber = 546787;
```

this returns nothing.

However if I type

```
Select * 
from MyTable
where LoanNumber in (12345, 546787)
```

it returns both rows. Why is this happening?

Comment: because one row can not have both values at the same time in the same column

Comment: A LoanNumber can't be both 12345 and 546787 at the same time, it's either one or the other, not both.

Comment: Because how *can* `LoanNumber` have the value `12345` **and** `546787` at the same time? `IN` is similar to `WHERE LoanNumber = 12345 OR LoanNumber = 54678;` It'll bring back rows where `LoanNumber` has either of those values.

Comment: `AND` works, which is why you don't get any results. `LoanNumber` can't be both 12345  and 546787 at the same time. It's either one or the other

Comment: if you change the `AND` into `OR` it will work again

Comment: Did you confuse `AND` with `OR` perhaps?

Comment: Yea thats what it is IN is similar to OR

Comment: `AND` works.  Your query doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the evaluation is on a row per row basis. A row can't have 2 different values for a column; it can't be both `12345` **and** `546787` in the same row.

If you change the `AND` for an `OR`, it will return the same results as using `IN`.

Answer (score 2):

your rows probably look like

```
id   loannumber   other columns
--   ----------   -------------
1    12345        etc...
2    546787       more etc...
...
```

**when you write**

```
Select * 
from MyTable 
where LoanNumber = 12345 and LoanNumber =546787;
```

you instruct sql server to look for every row like this

```
for every row in MyTable
  does this row have value 12345 in LoanNumber
  and does this row also have value 546787 in LoanNumber
  If both condtions are true then return this row
```

Both conditions must be true (because you wrote AND) and that is off course impossible

**when you write**

```
Select * 
from MyTable 
where LoanNumber = 12345 OR LoanNumber =546787;
```

or

```
Select * 
from MyTable 
where LoanNumber in (12345, 546787);
```

you instruct sql server to look for every row like this

```
 for every row in MyTable  
   does this row have value 12345 in LoanNumber  
   if not, then does this row have value 546787 in LoanNumber  
   If ONE of the condtions are true then return this row
```

Only one conditions must be true (because you wrote OR or IN)

As mentioned in comments and other answers, the database will do its comparision on a row basis.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` means `LoanNumber` is equal to any of values specified.
Logically it is **OR** not **AND**.